# The election failed. No new era is planned

Tags: polkadot, substrate-node-template, kusama, substrate-parachain-template

I set up the private network of 8/10, everything is working fine, all the validators validate the blocks but after the an era I am facing an issue that the **staking.StakingElectionFailed. The election failed. No new era is planned.**
I don't know how to fix this. I followed this link
https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/issues/7607#issuecomment-1129752912
and also followed other link to purge the chain but still facing this issue that the era time is not completing. I have many scenario in which I am facing the same issue of era completion 8/10 private network is one of them.

[image]
After this I again the setup the private network of 10/10 and this time everything is working fine but i want to know that why there is era time completion issue when i setup the 8/10 private network

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Why

Check the PolkadotJS [algorithm](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/blob/master/packages/api-derive/src/session/progress.ts#L31).

```
info.currentIndex.sub(activeEraStartSessionIndex).imul(info.sessionLength).iadd(sessionProgress);
```

Due to the election failure. [`ErasStartSessionIndex`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/23bb5a6255bbcd7ce2999044710428bc4a7a924f/frame/staking/src/pallet/impls.rs#L417) won't be updated. So, the PolkadotApps get a ridiculously big number.

[image]

You could check your log:

```sh
journalctl -u darwinia-node.service | grep "election provider failed"
Sep 08 06:32:18 pangoro-g1 drml[136952]: 2022-09-08 06:32:18 [14058]  election provider failed due to ElectionError::Fallback("NoFallback.")
```

I guess you encounter the same error as me.

---

#### The easiest way to fix

To solve this, you just need to change the [`Fallback`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/23bb5a6255bbcd7ce2999044710428bc4a7a924f/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L713) to `frame_election_provider_support::onchain::OnChainSequentialPhragmen<Runtime>`. I guess you have set it to `NoFallback` before.

Because your validator set is pretty small, on-chain computation is totally fine.

---

#### Debug & other fixes

Check the logs in [`feasibility_check`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/1dcb9ceea7e252eb779f044448bc693ec6161baf/frame/election-provider-multi-phase/src/lib.rs#L1453) to find out what's the root cause.

You need to know that once you enter the emergency mode with `NoFallback`, that is a [dead loop](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/1dcb9ceea7e252eb779f044448bc693ec6161baf/frame/election-provider-multi-phase/src/lib.rs#L733-L808).

You've to do one of these to recover the election:

- force set [`CurrentPhase`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/1dcb9ceea7e252eb779f044448bc693ec6161baf/frame/election-provider-multi-phase/src/lib.rs#L1217) with root
- calculate the result with offchain tool then submit it through [`set_emergency_election_result`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/1dcb9ceea7e252eb779f044448bc693ec6161baf/frame/election-provider-multi-phase/src/lib.rs#L956)
- change `NoFallback` to `OnChainSequentialPhragmen`

Comment: After applying this my chain is working fine. 
Thanks for the support