# Staking Election Failed (staking.StakingElectionFailed The election failed. No new era is planned. ) after adding EVM with NPOS(i.e BABE)

Tags: polkadot-js, pallet-staking, pallet-election-phragmen

I have Added EVM pallet to my NPOS based Substrate chain but i am facing **staking.StakingElectionFailed The election failed. No new era is planned.** how to solve this issue.

I have implemented the NPOS with EVM blockchain using the substrate.

NPOS working fine but after adding EVM to Genesis config in node the NPOS is not working and the staking election failed.

Smart Contracts working fine on the chain.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Check https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4802/the-election-failed-no-new-era-is-planned and try to log more information.

Comment: NPOS working fine but after adding EVM to Genesis config in node the NPOS is not working and the staking election failed.

Comment: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4802/the-election-failed-no-new-era-is-planned i have tried this but the problem is same

Comment: I mean, follow that guide and paste the log here. Which will help us to diagnose.

Comment: I am using polkadot-v0.9.25

  708 |     type Fallback = frame_election_provider_support::onchain::OnChainSequentialPhragmen<Runtime>;
      |                                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in `frame_election_provider_support::onchain`
I am getting this error while using this **frame_election_provider_support::onchain::OnChainSequentialPhragmen<Runtime>** as there is two struct which is BoundedExecution and UnbondedExecution

Comment: **I am using polkadot-v0.9.25**

Comment: **cannot find type `OnChainSequentialPhragmen` in module `frame_election_provider_support::onchain**

Comment: Try calling this with sudo: https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_election_provider_multi_phase/pallet/struct.Pallet.html#method.governance_fallback

Comment: As in the governance_fallback it is mentioned that **This can only be called when Phase::Emergency is enabled** but in my case there is no event of Phase::Emergency occur and I am getting this error after every era **staking.StakingElectionFailed
The election failed. No new era is planned. ** 
I also tried governance_fallback function with sudo but getting this error **error: electionProviderMultiPhase.CallNotAllowed** same for set_emergency_election_results 
41-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to this is chill your nominators/validators, and validate/nominate again so that new implementation will record your votes in `T::VoterList.` And maybe `forceNewEra()` using sudo account.  re-try a couple of times until you see staking.Elected.

Make sure you have setup a private network and you have minimum 3 validators.

Answer (score 1):

chilling the validators is not good practise as it is a 1 validator on network and if you do this your blockchain will stop you can do some other changes in you program you can add fallback in lib.rs to

`type Fallback = frame_election_provider_support::onchain::UnboundedExecution<OnChainSeqPhragmen>`